# Checkbox change state

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling with the following:

I want to write a value into a field if the state of a checkbox changes, and only then.

I have the following, but I don't know how to get it 100% right:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('control_COLUMN3').onchange = 
        function() {
            if(document.getElementById('control_COLUMN3').checked) 
            {
                 console.log('checked');
                 document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value = 
                 "checked";
            } 
            else 
            {
                 console.log('unchecked');
                 document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value = 
                 "empty";   
            }
        };
        </script>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;">
                    <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width:300px;" id="container_COLUMN3">
                        <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px;">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                <tr style="height: 20px">
                                    <td class="fieldLabel" style="">
                                        <label class="yesNoCheckboxLabel">
                                            <input type="checkbox"  name="City" id="control_COLUMN3" label="City">
                                            City</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Language" id="control_COLUMN15">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!
Loren

Comment: please show your html code

Comment: fyi: control_COLUMN3 is the id of my checkbox, control_COLUMN15 is the id of my textfield.

Comment: The use of change function is necessary to handle dynamic changes of checkbox value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use an `onchange` function and `.checked` to change the value of the second checkbox:

```js
document.querySelector('#control_COLUMN3').onchange = function() {

  if(document.getElementById('control_COLUMN3').checked) {
    console.log('checked');
    document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').checked = "checked";
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked');
    document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').checked = "";   
  };

}
```

```html
<input id="control_COLUMN3" type="checkbox">

<input id="control_COLUMN15" type="checkbox">
```

Updated following comment:

```js
function checkCheckbox() {

  if(document.getElementById('control_COLUMN3').checked) {
    console.log('checked');
    document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value = "checked";
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked');
    document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value = "empty";   
  };

}
```

```html
<input id="control_COLUMN3" type="checkbox" onChange="checkCheckbox()">

<input type="hidden" name="Language" id="control_COLUMN15">
```

Comment: Hi @SWC, I edited my code here above, but it's not doing what it's intended to do. Can you check please?

Comment: Looking at this more, I'm guessing the issue might be the JavaScript being added in the `head`. If it's added just before the `body` tag closes then it should work. I've also added a second method of doing this that would work in the `head`. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `.show()` to see input

```js
function changeCheckbox(){
if ($('#control_COLUMN3').is(':checked')) {
$('#control_COLUMN15').show();
$('#control_COLUMN15').val("checked");
}
else
$('#control_COLUMN15').val("unchecked");
$('#control_COLUMN15').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="control_COLUMN3" type="checkbox" onchange="changeCheckbox()">
 <input style="display:none" name="Language" id="control_COLUMN15">
```

**For your edit only javascript**

```js
   function changeCheckbox(){
    if (document.getElementById('control_COLUMN3').checked) {

   document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value="checked";
   document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').value="unchecked";
       document.getElementById('control_COLUMN15').style.display="block";
   
    }
```

```html
    <input id="control_COLUMN3" type="checkbox" onchange="changeCheckbox()">
     <input style="display:none" name="Language" id="control_COLUMN15">
```

Comment: tell me for more help